# Change event not Working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The value of to[0] is changing dynamically due to a javascript calender. In this code, change event is not working and I don't know...why so???
Jquery Code is:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("input[name='to[0]']").change( function() {
    var b1 = $("input[name='to[0]']").val();
    alert(b1);
  });
});
```

HTML for this field is:

```
<td >
            <input type="text" size="12" name="to[0]" value="To" readonly="readonly" />
              <a class="datepicker" href="#"><img alt="Pick a date" src="js/date.gif" border="0" width="17" height="16" /></a>
</td>
```

This is date.js file for calender

```
                                var datePickerDivID = "datepicker";
                        var iFrameDivID = "datepickeriframe";

                        var dayArrayShort = new Array('Su', 'Mo', 'Tu', 'We', 'Th', 'Fr', 'Sa');
                        var dayArrayMed = new Array('Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat');
                        var dayArrayLong = new Array('Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday');
                        var monthArrayShort = new Array('Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec');
                        var monthArrayMed = new Array('Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec');
                        var monthArrayLong = new Array('January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December');

                        // these variables define the date formatting we're expecting and outputting.
                        // If you want to use a different format by default, change the defaultDateSeparator
                        // and defaultDateFormat variables either here or on your HTML page.
                        var defaultDateSeparator = "/";        // common values would be "/" or "."
                        var defaultDateFormat = "dMy"    // valid values are "mdy", "dmy", and "ymd"
                        var dateSeparator = defaultDateSeparator;
                        var dateFormat = defaultDateFormat;
                        function displayDatePicker(dateFieldName, displayBelowThisObject, dtFormat, dtSep)
                        {
                            var targetDateField = document.getElementsByName(dateFieldName).item(0);

                            // if we weren't told what node to display the datepicker beneath, just display it
                            // beneath the date field we're updating
                            if (!displayBelowThisObject)
                                displayBelowThisObject = targetDateField;

                            // if a date separator character was given, update the dateSeparator variable
                            if (dtSep)
                                dateSeparator = dtSep;
                            else
                                dateSeparator = defaultDateSeparator;

                            // if a date format was given, update the dateFormat variable
                            if (dtFormat)
                                dateFormat = dtFormat;
                            else
                                dateFormat = defaultDateFormat;

                            var x = displayBelowThisObject.offsetLeft;
                            var y = displayBelowThisObject.offsetTop + displayBelowThisObject.offsetHeight ;

                            // deal with elements inside tables and such
                            var parent = displayBelowThisObject;
                            while (parent.offsetParent) {
                                parent = parent.offsetParent;
                                x += parent.offsetLeft;
                                y += parent.offsetTop ;
                            }

                            drawDatePicker(targetDateField, x, y);
                        }


                        /**
                        Draw the datepicker object (which is just a table with calendar elements) at the
                        specified x and y coordinates, using the targetDateField object as the input tag
                        that will ultimately be populated with a date.

                        This function will normally be called by the displayDatePicker function.
                        */
                        function drawDatePicker(targetDateField, x, y)
                        {
                            var dt = getFieldDate(targetDateField.value );
                            // the datepicker table will be drawn inside of a <div> with an ID defined by the
                            // global datePickerDivID variable. If such a div doesn't yet exist on the HTML
                            // document we're working with, add one.
                            if (!document.getElementById(datePickerDivID)) {
                                // don't use innerHTML to update the body, because it can cause global variables
                                // that are currently pointing to objects on the page to have bad references
                                //document.body.innerHTML += "<div id='" + datePickerDivID + "' class='dpDiv'></div>";
                                var newNode = document.createElement("div");
                                newNode.setAttribute("id", datePickerDivID);
                                newNode.setAttribute("class", "dpDiv");
                                newNode.setAttribute("style", "visibility: hidden;");
                                document.body.appendChild(newNode);
                            }

                            // move the datepicker div to the proper x,y coordinate and toggle the visiblity
                            var pickerDiv = document.getElementById(datePickerDivID);
                            pickerDiv.style.position = "absolute";
                            pickerDiv.style.left = x + "px";
                            pickerDiv.style.top = y + "px";
                            pickerDiv.style.visibility = (pickerDiv.style.visibility == "visible" ? "hidden" : "visible");
                            pickerDiv.style.display = (pickerDiv.style.display == "block" ? "none" : "block");
                            pickerDiv.style.zIndex = 10000;

                            // draw the datepicker table
                            refreshDatePicker(targetDateField.name, dt.getFullYear(), dt.getMonth(), dt.getDate());
                        }


                        /**
                        This is the function that actually draws the datepicker calendar.
                        */
                        function refreshDatePicker(dateFieldName, year, month, day)
                        {
                            // if no arguments are passed, use today's date; otherwise, month and year
                            // are required (if a day is passed, it will be highlighted later)
                            var thisDay = new Date();

                            if ((month >= 0) && (year > 0)) {
                                thisDay = new Date(year, month, 1);
                            } else {
                                day = thisDay.getDate();
                                thisDay.setDate(1);
                            }

                            // the calendar will be drawn as a table
                            // you can customize the table elements with a global CSS style sheet,
                            // or by hardcoding style and formatting elements below
                            var crlf = "\r\n";
                            var TABLE = "<table cols=7 class='dpTable'>" + crlf;
                            var xTABLE = "</table>" + crlf;
                            var TR = "<tr class='dpTR'>";
                            var TR_title = "<tr class='dpTitleTR'>";
                            var TR_days = "<tr class='dpDayTR'>";
                            var TR_todaybutton = "<tr class='dpTodayButtonTR'>";
                            var xTR = "</tr>" + crlf;
                            var TD = "<td class='dpTD' onMouseOut='this.className=\"dpTD\";' onMouseOver=' this.className=\"dpTDHover\";' ";    // leave this tag open, because we'll be adding an onClick event
                            var TD_title = "<td colspan=5 class='dpTitleTD'>";
                            var TD_buttons = "<td class='dpButtonTD'>";
                            var TD_todaybutton = "<td colspan=7 class='dpTodayButtonTD'>";
                            var TD_days = "<td class='dpDayTD'>";
                            var TD_selected = "<td class='dpDayHighlightTD' onMouseOut='this.className=\"dpDayHighlightTD\";' onMouseOver='this.className=\"dpTDHover\";' ";    // leave this tag open, because we'll be adding an onClick event
                            var xTD = "</td>" + crlf;
                            var DIV_title = "<div class='dpTitleText'>";
                            var DIV_selected = "<div class='dpDayHighlight'>";
                            var xDIV = "</div>";

                            // start generating the code for the calendar table
                            var html = TABLE;

                            // this is the title bar, which displays the month and the buttons to
                            // go back to a previous month or forward to the next month
                            html += TR_title;
                            html += TD_buttons + getButtonCode(dateFieldName, thisDay, -1, "&lt;") + xTD;
                            html += TD_title + DIV_title + monthArrayLong[ thisDay.getMonth()] + " " + thisDay.getFullYear() + xDIV + xTD;
                            html += TD_buttons + getButtonCode(dateFieldName, thisDay, 1, "&gt;") + xTD;
                            html += xTR;

                            // this is the row that indicates which day of the week we're on
                            html += TR_days;
                            for(i = 0; i < dayArrayShort.length; i++)
                                html += TD_days + dayArrayShort[i] + xTD;
                            html += xTR;

                            // now we'll start populating the table with days of the month
                            html += TR;

                            // first, the leading blanks
                            for (i = 0; i < thisDay.getDay(); i++)
                                html += TD + "&nbsp;" + xTD;

                            // now, the days of the month
                            do {
                                dayNum = thisDay.getDate();
                                TD_onclick = " onclick=\"updateDateField('" + dateFieldName + "', '" + getDateString(thisDay) + "');\">";

                                if (dayNum == day)
                                    html += TD_selected + TD_onclick + DIV_selected + dayNum + xDIV + xTD;
                                else
                                    html += TD + TD_onclick + dayNum + xTD;

                                // if this is a Saturday, start a new row
                                if (thisDay.getDay() == 6)
                                    html += xTR + TR;

                                // increment the day
                                thisDay.setDate(thisDay.getDate() + 1);
                            } while (thisDay.getDate() > 1)

                            // fill in any trailing blanks
                            if (thisDay.getDay() > 0) {
                                for (i = 6; i > thisDay.getDay(); i--)
                                    html += TD + "&nbsp;" + xTD;
                            }
                            html += xTR;

                            // add a button to allow the user to easily return to today, or close the calendar
                            var today = new Date();
                            var todayString = "Today is " + dayArrayMed[today.getDay()] + ", " + monthArrayMed[ today.getMonth()] + " " + today.getDate();
                            html += TR_todaybutton + TD_todaybutton;
                            html += "<button class='dpTodayButton' onClick='refreshDatePicker(\"" + dateFieldName + "\");'>this month</button> ";
                        //  html += "<button class='dpTodayButton' onClick='updateDateField(\"" + dateFieldName + "\");'>close</button>";
                            html += xTD + xTR;

                            // and finally, close the table
                            html += xTABLE;

                            document.getElementById(datePickerDivID).innerHTML = html;
                            // add an "iFrame shim" to allow the datepicker to display above selection lists
                            adjustiFrame();
                        }


                        /**
                        Convenience function for writing the code for the buttons that bring us back or forward
                        a month.
                        */
                        function getButtonCode(dateFieldName, dateVal, adjust, label)
                        {
                            var newMonth = (dateVal.getMonth () + adjust) % 12;
                            var newYear = dateVal.getFullYear() + parseInt((dateVal.getMonth() + adjust) / 12);
                            if (newMonth < 0) {
                                newMonth += 12;
                                newYear += -1;
                            }

                            return "<button class='dpButton' onClick='refreshDatePicker(\"" + dateFieldName + "\", " + newYear + ", " + newMonth + ");'>" + label + "</button>";
                        }


                        /**
                        Convert a JavaScript Date object to a string, based on the dateFormat and dateSeparator
                        variables at the beginning of this script library.
                        */
                        function getDateString(dateVal)
                        {//alert(dateVal );
                            var dayString = "00" + dateVal.getDate();
                            var monthString = "00" + (dateVal.getMonth()+1);
                            dayString = dayString.substring(dayString.length - 2);
                            monthString = monthString.substring(monthString.length - 2);

                            switch (dateFormat) {
                                case "dmy" :
                                    return dayString + dateSeparator + monthString + dateSeparator + dateVal.getFullYear();
                                case "ymd" :
                                    return dateVal.getFullYear() + dateSeparator + monthString + dateSeparator + dayString;
                                case "mdy" :
                             return dateVal.getFullYear() + dateSeparator + monthString + dateSeparator + dayString;
                                default :
                                    return monthString + dateSeparator + dayString + dateSeparator + dateVal.getFullYear();
                            }
                        }

                        /**
                        Convert a string to a JavaScript Date object.
                        */
                        function getFieldDate(dateString)
                        {
                            var dateVal;
                            var dArray;
                            var d, m, y;

                            try {
                                dArray = splitDateString(dateString);
                                if (dArray) {
                                    switch (dateFormat) {
                                        case "dmy" :
                                            d = parseInt(dArray[0], 10);
                                            m = parseInt(dArray[1], 10) - 1;
                                            y = parseInt(dArray[2], 10);
                                            break;
                                        case "ymd" :
                                            d = parseInt(dArray[2], 10);
                                            m = parseInt(dArray[1], 10) - 1;
                                            y = parseInt(dArray[0], 10);
                                            break;
                                        case "mdy" :
                                        default :
                                            d = parseInt(dArray[1], 10);
                                            m = parseInt(dArray[0], 10) - 1;
                                            y = parseInt(dArray[2], 10);
                                            break;
                                    }
                                    dateVal = new Date(y, m, d);
                                } else if (dateString) {
                                    dateVal = new Date(dateString);
                                } else {
                                    dateVal = new Date();
                                }
                            } catch(e) {
                                dateVal = new Date();
                            }

                            return dateVal;
                        }


                        /**
                        Try to split a date string into an array of elements, using common date separators.
                        If the date is split, an array is returned; otherwise, we just return false.
                        */
                        function splitDateString(dateString)
                        {
                            var dArray;
                            if (dateString.indexOf("/") >= 0)
                                dArray = dateString.split("/");
                            else if (dateString.indexOf(".") >= 0)
                                dArray = dateString.split(".");
                            else if (dateString.indexOf("-") >= 0)
                                dArray = dateString.split("-");
                            else if (dateString.indexOf("\\") >= 0)
                                dArray = dateString.split("\\");
                            else
                                dArray = false;

                            return dArray;
                        }

                        /**
                        Update the field with the given dateFieldName with the dateString that has been passed,
                        and hide the datepicker. If no dateString is passed, just close the datepicker without
                        changing the field value.

                        Also, if the page developer has defined a function called datePickerClosed anywhere on
                        the page or in an imported library, we will attempt to run that function with the updated
                        field as a parameter. This can be used for such things as date validation, setting default
                        values for related fields, etc. For example, you might have a function like this to validate
                        a start date field:
                        */
                        function datePickerClosed(dateField)
                        {
                            var dateObj = getFieldDate(dateField.value);
                            var today = new Date();
                            today = new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth(), today.getDate());

                            if (dateField.name == "StartDate") {
                                if (dateObj < today) {
                                    // if the date is before today, alert the user and display the datepicker again
                                    alert("Please enter a date that is today or later");
                                    dateField.value = "";
                                    document.getElementById(datePickerDivID).style.visibility = "visible";
                                    adjustiFrame();
                                } else {
                                    // if the date is okay, set the EndDate field to 7 days after the StartDate
                                    dateObj.setTime(dateObj.getTime() + (7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
                                    var endDateField = document.getElementsByName ("EndDate").item(0);
                                    endDateField.value = getDateString(dateObj);
                                }
                            }
                        }

                        function updateDateField(dateFieldName, dateString)
                        {//alert('hi');
                            var x=dateString.split('-');
                            var month;
                            if(x[1]==01)
                            {
                             month=monthArrayMed[0]; 
                            }
                            else if(x[1]==02)
                            {
                             month=monthArrayMed[1]; 
                            }
                                else if(x[1]==03)
                            {
                             month=monthArrayMed[2]; 
                            }
                                else if(x[1]==04)
                            {
                             month=monthArrayMed[3]; 
                            }
                                else if(x[1]==05)
                            {
                             month=monthArrayMed[4]; 
                            }
                                else if(x[1]==06)
                            {
                             month=monthArrayMed[5]; 
                            }
                                else if(x[1]==07)
                            {
                             month=monthArrayMed[6]; 
                            }
                                else if(x[1]==08)
                            {
                             month=monthArrayMed[7]; 
                            }
                                else if(x[1]==09)
                            {
                             month=monthArrayMed[8]; 
                            }
                                else if(x[1]==10)
                            {
                             month=monthArrayMed[9]; 
                            }
                                else if(x[1]==11)
                            {
                             month=monthArrayMed[10]; 
                            }
                                else if(x[1]==12)
                            {
                             month=monthArrayMed[11]; 
                            }
                            dateString=x[0]+'-'+month+'-'+x[2];
                            var targetDateField = document.getElementsByName (dateFieldName).item(0);
                            if (dateString)
                                targetDateField.value = dateString;

                            var pickerDiv = document.getElementById(datePickerDivID);
                            pickerDiv.style.visibility = "hidden";
                            pickerDiv.style.display = "none";

                            adjustiFrame();
                            targetDateField.focus();
                            // after the datepicker has closed, optionally run a user-defined function called
                            // datePickerClosed, passing the field that was just updated as a parameter
                            // (note that this will only run if the user actually selected a date from the datepicker)
                         if ((dateString) && (typeof(datePickerClosed) == "function"))
                         {
                                datePickerClosed(targetDateField);
                            //alert(typeof(datePickerClosed));
                         }
                            //alert(typeof(datePickerClosed));
                        }


                        function adjustiFrame(pickerDiv, iFrameDiv)
                        {
                            // we know that Opera doesn't like something about this, so if we
                            // think we're using Opera, don't even try
                            var is_opera = (navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf("opera") != -1);
                            if (is_opera)
                                return;

                            // put a try/catch block around the whole thing, just in case
                            try {
                                if (!document.getElementById(iFrameDivID)) {
                                    // don't use innerHTML to update the body, because it can cause global variables
                                    // that are currently pointing to objects on the page to have bad references
                                    //document.body.innerHTML += "<iframe id='" + iFrameDivID + "' src='javascript:false;' scrolling='no' frameborder='0'>";
                                    var newNode = document.createElement("iFrame");
                                    newNode.setAttribute("id", iFrameDivID);
                                    newNode.setAttribute("src", "javascript:false;");
                                    newNode.setAttribute("scrolling", "no");
                                    newNode.setAttribute ("frameborder", "0");
                                    document.body.appendChild(newNode);
                                }

                                if (!pickerDiv)
                                    pickerDiv = document.getElementById(datePickerDivID);
                                if (!iFrameDiv)
                                    iFrameDiv = document.getElementById(iFrameDivID);

                                try {
                                    iFrameDiv.style.position = "absolute";
                                    iFrameDiv.style.width = pickerDiv.offsetWidth;
                                    iFrameDiv.style.height = pickerDiv.offsetHeight ;
                                    iFrameDiv.style.top = pickerDiv.style.top;
                                    iFrameDiv.style.left = pickerDiv.style.left;
                                    iFrameDiv.style.zIndex = pickerDiv.style.zIndex - 1;
                                    iFrameDiv.style.visibility = pickerDiv.style.visibility ;
                                    iFrameDiv.style.display = pickerDiv.style.display;
                                } catch(e) {
                                }

                            } catch (ee) {
                            }

                        }
```

Comment: what datepicker library are you using?

Comment: if the value of your input is changed dinamycally by datepicker (and not by user action), the `change` event won't be fired

Comment: @SANDEEP this is just a class. I have one of my own javascript for calender....

Comment: @Calderan....user has to click on calender to change the value..

Comment: but the value is not inserted by your hands... I suppose it's datepicker script that changes the input value. see http://jsfiddle.net/RxsL8/1/ the alert is never fired if you press the button

Comment: yes....it is a script for getting the date...

Comment: @F.Calderan seems to be right, I tested it in http://jsfiddle.net/8QSjH/ and event is only fired when you manually change the input value, not when JavaScript changes it for you

Comment: As you mentioned that you have your own javascript for the calender, so in that javascript you put this jquery code. I mean when the value of the inputbox is changed by the javascript code you an put this code

Comment: I have included that file for calender...and I call it's functions using jquery.

Answer (score 1):

Use this code instead of your code:

```
$("input:text[name=to[0]]").blur( function() {
    var b1 = $(this).val();
    alert(b1);
  });
```

Comment: every function is working except 'change' without changing the code...anyway..Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 1):

As shown on http://jsfiddle.net/RxsL8/1/ `change` event is never fired for an input if its value is changed dinamycally (and not by explicit user action)

so you would probably need to use some internal function/callbacks provided by your datepicker plugin, or add some code to run when a date is chosen

---

after your edit:

your input is updated on `updateDateField` function, right here

```
if (dateString)
     targetDateField.value = dateString;
```

so add here a callback function

Comment: Act..I read that already..but didn't quite understand it..
Now I know what is wrong..so let me try something. Thanks for your help.

Comment: you should at least tell what datepicker you're using and update your post with this information

Comment: ok...done that...now I need 1 more help from you..In here one field named to[0] is used...but actually I have them 'N' times with the +1 in index (to[1],to[2] etc)..which are generating due to cloning...
same goes for from[0]. from[0] is start date and to[0] is end date. I am comparing these two dates for end date not to be less than the start date. Now I am not getting a way for selecting these element since the name are generating dynamically..and I want to select it using name since this is only different thing.

Comment: my question is here..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10652102/comparing-two-dates-n-times-using-jquery