# Comparing two dates N times using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In here one field named to[0] is used...but actually I have them 'N' times with the +1 in index (to[1],to[2] etc)..which are generating due to cloning... same goes for from[0]. from[0] is start date and to[0] is end date.
I am comparing these two dates for end date not to be less than the start date. 
Here first 2 blocks of code are working properly because each is for  one row.  But whenever I am trying to make it for 'N' rows, it isn't working i.e. the  last block of code isn't working.

I am not getting a way for selecting these element since the name are generating dynamically...

Jquery Code Is:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
                $("input[name='to[0]']").blur( function() {
                    if ($("input[name='to[0]']").val() != 'To' && $("input[name='from[0]']").val() != 'From') {
                        var a1 = $("input[name='from[0]']").val();
                        var b1 = $("input[name='to[0]']").val();
                        alert(b1);alert(a1);
                        if (a1 > b1) {
                                    alert("Invalid Date Range!\nStart Date cannot be after End Date!");
                        }
                    }
                });
                $("input[name='to[1]']").blur( function() {
                    if ($("input[name='to[1]']").val() != 'To' && $("input[name='from[1]']").val() != 'From') {
                        var a1 = $("input[name='from[1]']").val();
                        var b1 = $("input[name='to[1]']").val();
                        alert(b1);alert(a1);
                        if (a1 > b1) {
                                    alert("Invalid Date Range!\nStart Date cannot be after End Date!");
                        }
                    }
                });
                $("td.date").click( function() {
                    var n = $('#table2 tbody>tr').length - 2;
                    var r=2;
                    $("td.date>input:first").next().blur( function() {
                        while(r<n) {
                            if ($("input[name='to[r]']").val() != 'To' && $("input[name='from[r]']").val() != 'From') {
                                var a1 = $("input[name='from[r]']").val();
                                var b1 = $("input[name='to[r]']").val();
                                alert(b1);alert(a1);
                                if (a1 > b1) {
                                            alert("Invalid Date Range!\nStart Date cannot be after End Date!");
                                }
                            }
                            r++;
                        }
                    });
                });
```

HTML is..

```
 <td width="15%" align="center" >
            <input class="f" style="width:70px" type="text" size="12" name="from[0]"  value="From" readonly="readonly"  />
            <a class="datepicker" href="#"><img alt="Pick a date" src="js/date.gif" border="0" width="17" height="16" /></a>
         </td>
         <td width="15%" align="center" >
            <input style="width:70px" class="f" type="text" size="12" name="to[0]" value="To" readonly="readonly" />
              <a class="datepicker" href="#"><img alt="Pick a date" src="js/date.gif" border="0" width="17" height="16" /></a>
         </td>

  <td width="15%" align="center" class="date" >
            <input style="width:70px" type="text" size="12" name="from[1]"  value="From" readonly="readonly"  />
            <a class="datepicker" href="#"><img alt="Pick a date" src="js/date.gif" border="0" width="17" height="16" /></a>
         </td>
         <td width="15%" align="center" class="date" >
            <input style="width:70px" class="f" type="text" size="12" name="to[1]" value="To" readonly="readonly" />
              <a class="datepicker" href="#"><img alt="Pick a date" src="js/date.gif" border="0" width="17" height="16"  /></a>
         </td>
```

last row which contains  td for from[1] and to[1] is getting cloned and after that  last row gets cloned...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change your selector, then you don't need to duplicate the code. Try this:

```
//^= means name starts with, so we are selecting all inputs with that matcher
$("input[name^='to['").blur( function() {
    //first we get the name in a variable (just for shortness)
    var thisName = $(this).prop("name");
    //we then get the numbered index, by splitting the id of the current item
    var index = thisName.substring(thisName.indexOf("[") + 1).replace("]", "");
    //based on the index, we now can get the corresponding "from" field
    var correspondingFromField = $("input[name='from[" + index + "]']");
    //now we just do your logic:
    if ($(this).val() != 'To' && correspondingFromField.val() != 'From') {
        var a1 = correspondingFromField.val();
        var b1 = $(this).val();
        alert(b1);alert(a1);
        if (a1 > b1) {
            alert("Invalid Date Range!\nStart Date cannot be after End Date!");
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: '......this error occurs when I changed my code to yours...

Comment: I tried...but the error is same as before....I think problem is here
"input[name='from["

Comment: @mattytommo..Can you explain me what your code does...may be then I can debug  it a bit to  solve the problem...

Comment: @MayankAwasthi I've fixed it again, I'd missed a `]` off. I've now added a line-by-line explanation of the code in order for you to help debug it :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the counter as part of the selector, but you're hardcoding it to be `r`.  Try this:

```
while(r<n) {
    if ($('input[name="to\\[' + r + '\\]"]').val() != 'To' && $('input[name="from\\[' + r + '\\]"]').val() != 'From') {
        var a1 = $('input[name="from\\[' + r + '\\]"]').val();
        var b1 = $('input[name="to\\[' + r + '\\]"]').val();
        alert(b1);alert(a1);
        if (a1 > b1) {
            alert("Invalid Date Range!\nStart Date cannot be after End Date!");
        }
    }
    r++;
}
```